# Angular JS - key inside an object as variable

Tags: angularjs

I have a variable defined, and a scope in order to apply a filter in Angular:

```
var tochange = "Ferrari";
$scope.filter = { cars :{ tochange : true}};
```

I would like the `tochange` variable inside the scope to change when I change its value outside the scope, but with this code it doesn't work as expected. You can check the JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aauq4rgL/)

Edit: changed the jsfiddle url, now it should work ok.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't totally understand what you are trying to do. Maybe add some code to the fiddle with what you've tried?

Comment: The already provided answer answers it perfect, I will accept as soon as I can, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use bracket notation to use a variable as a key, but you have to declare the object separately (unless you can use some ES6 syntax)

```
var tochange = "Ferrari";
var obj = {};
obj[tochange] = true;
$scope.filter = { cars : obj};
```

Or ES6:

```
$scope.filter = { cars :{ [tochange] : true}};
```